# Python: Change one printed character

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter, terminal

I'm making a game with a terminal UI, and the current code is as follows

```
from ast import Pass
from re import findall
from time import sleep
from ScrFX import invalidOption
from os import system
from getkey import getkey, keys


def main_menu():
    hobo = "**********************************************\n" #ho horizontal, bo border
    vebo = "**                                          **\n" #ve vertical, bo border
    op1 =  "**             1) Start Game                **\n"
    op2 =  "**             2) Load  Game                **\n"
    op3 =  "**             3) Quit  Game                **\n"
    s = "\n"
    mainmenuscreen = (hobo+(vebo*5)+op1+vebo+op2+vebo+op3+vebo+(vebo*5)+hobo)
    print(mainmenuscreen)
    print("Please choose an option\n")
    def userkey():
        usse = getkey() #us-er, se-lection
        if usse == '1':
            print("Start game")
        elif usse == '2':
            print("load game")
        elif usse == '3':
            system('cls')
            print("Goodbye!")
            quit()
        elif usse == '0':
            print("Secret Menu yay)")
        else:
            invalidOption()
            system('cls')
            print(mainmenuscreen)
            userkey()
        return(usse)
    userkey()

main_menu()
```

Now, I want to be able to have a symbol (let's say ¤) that goes to before the option so something like this:

```
op1 =  "**             1) Start Game                **\n"
op2 =  "**       ¤     2) Load  Game                **\n"
op3 =  "**             3) Quit  Game                **\n"
```

I know I can theoretically bruteforce my way by just changing the printed text values, clearing the screen, and printing it again; but i'm looking for a more elegant way to do it; I remember in BASIC there was a set command to set a specific line in a grid to a specific character, maybe there's something like this in python?

Also, before you say I should use tkinter for GUI; I understand where you come from but learning tkinter is literally like learning to program all over again, having said that I know tkinter is not the best option so I'm open to other libs before starting to commit to one; yet not ready still to commit to one at all.

Comment: Tkinter is good and there is no good reason to leave it and commit to another gui toolkit such as pyautogui or pyQt5.

Comment: *Also, before you say I should use tkinter for GUI; I understand where you come from but learning tkinter is literally like learning to program all over again, having said that I know tkinter is not the best option so I'm open to other libs before starting to commit to one* Why do you tag it then as `tkinter` question ? I don't think it gets much more simpler than tkinter, but that is just my **opinion** and [so] strictly try to avoid such discussion. So I'm voting to close it.